# Replace multiple words with a word single word

Tags: r, string, replace, gsub

I want to replace multiple letters/words with a single letter/word, multiple times in a dataframe. As an example,

Some data:

```
df = data.frame(
      a = 1:8, 
      b = c("colour1 o", "colour2 O", "colour3 out",  "colour4 Out", 
            "soundi i", "soundr I", "sounde in", "soundw In"))

df
  a           b
1 1   colour1 o
2 2   colour2 O
3 3   colour3 out
4 4   colour4 Out
5 5    soundi i
6 6    soundr I
7 7    sounde in
8 8    soundw In
```

Here is what I want to replace with:

```
df_repl <- list(
  O = c("o", "out", "Out"),
  In = c("i", "in", "I"))
```

So in `df$b` `o`, `out` and `Out` should become `O` and `i`, `in` and `I` become `In`, but only if they are separated from any other words by a space, so `o` in `colour` is not capitalised.

This gets me half way there, but I think I need another nested for-loop to move through `df_repl`...

```
for (word in df_repl[[1]]){
  patt <- paste0('\\b', word, '\\b')
  repl <- paste(names(df_repl[1]))
  df$b <- gsub(patt, repl, df$b)
}

df
  a         b
1 1 colour1 O
2 2 colour2 O
3 3 colour3 O
4 4 colour4 O
5 5  soundi i
6 6  soundr I
7 7  sounde in
8 8  soundw In
```

Above `o`, `out` and `Out` become `O` but `i`, `in` and `I` are not altered, here is the desired output:

```
  a         b
1 1 colour1 O
2 2 colour2 O
3 3 colour3 O
4 4 colour4 O
5 5  soundi In
6 6  soundr In
7 7  sounde In
8 8  soundw In
```

In the real data there are many more than two replacement words/letters so I can't just rerun the for-loop again. I'm not tied to a for-loop solution, but preferably using base R, any suggestions much appreciated.

**EDIT**

Trying to clarify my question:

Whenever one of `o`, `out` or `Out` occur in `df$b` I want to replace it with `O`

Whenever one of `i`, `in` or `I` occur in `df$b` I want to replace it with `In`

I can achieve the desired output like this:

```
for (word in df_repl[[1]]){
  patt <- paste0('\\b', word, '\\b')
  repl <- paste(names(df_repl[1]))
  df$b <- gsub(patt, repl, df$b)
}

for (word in df_repl[[2]]){
  patt <- paste0('\\b', word, '\\b')
  repl <- paste(names(df_repl[2]))
  df$b <- gsub(patt, repl, df$b)
}
```

But in my real dataset `df_repl` is length 50 rather two so I don't want to copy/paste/edit/rerun the for-loop 50 times

Comment: Just an extra point: It appears that `b` contains two pieces of information. Your data management and analysis could be easier to have two separate variables for it in the first place, and you could always us them later together for analysis and presentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can skip the loop over the words in `df_repl` when you paste them with `|` (or) between the words like:

```
for(i in names(df_repl)) {
    df$b <- sub(paste(paste0("\\b",df_repl[[i]],"\\b"), collapse = "|")
                , i, df$b)
}
df
#  a         b
#1 1 colour1 O
#2 2 colour2 O
#3 3 colour3 O
#4 4 colour4 O
#5 5 soundi In
#6 6 soundr In
#7 7 sounde In
#8 8 soundw In
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try using three separate calls to `sub`:

```
df$b <- sub("\\bo\\b", "i", df$b)
df$b <- sub("\\bout\\b", "in", df$b)
df$b <- sub("\\bOut\\b", "I", df$b)

df

  a          b
1 1  colour1 i
2 2  colour2 O
3 3 colour3 in
4 4  colour4 I
5 5   soundi i
6 6   soundr I
7 7  sounde in
8 8  soundw In
```

To automate this, you could try using `sapply` with an index:

```
terms_in <- c("o", "out", "Out")
pat <- paste0("\\b", terms_in, "\\b")
replace <- c("i", "in", "I")
sapply(seq_along(pat), function(x) {
    df$b <<- sub(pat[x], replace[x], df$b)
})
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But in my real data I have 10's - 100's of replacements I want to do so I would prefer to loop over something like my df_repl variable instead of making 100's of individuals calls.

Comment: @flee I gave you an option to automate this using `sapply`.  Not sure if it be the most optimal code, but all you would need is two vectors of the search terms and their replacements.

Comment: I have had a go at implementing your automated solution using `sapply`, but cannot easily produce my desired output above. Are you able to post a reproducible answer?

Comment: My code seems to be working [in this demo](https://rextester.com/AVZY77778).

Comment: It runs, but it does not produce the desired output (shown at the end of my question). My desired output has the first four row endings converted  to `O` and the second four rows ending in `In`. With your `sapply` function the rows end in `i`, `O`, `in`, `I`, `i`, `I`, `in` and `In`.

Comment: _Edit_ your question and show us the actual replacement rules.  I used only what you gave above.

Comment: Question updated, hopefully that clarifies what I am trying to do.

Comment: It might be easier for you to modify my code as you need.  Just add search and replace terms to the vectors `terms_in` and `replace` as you need.  I don't see any changes in your question TBH.

Answer (score 1):

This is another solution:

```
library(stringr)
in1 <- str_split(df$b, " ", simplify = TRUE)[,1]
in2 <- str_split(df$b, " ", simplify = TRUE)[,2]

in2[in2 %in% c("o", "out", "Out")] <- "O"
in2[in2 %in% c("i", "in", "I")] <- "In"
df$b <- paste(in1, in2, sep=" ") 
df
```

If you have a long list of words in your data, you could also move `c(word list)`  outside:

```
in1<- str_split(df$b, " ", simplify = TRUE)[,1]
in2<- str_split(df$b, " ", simplify = TRUE)[,2]
o <- c("o", "Out", "Out")
i <- c("i", "in", "I") 
in2[in2 %in% o] <- "O"
in2[in2 %in% i] <- "In"
df$b <- paste(in1, in2, sep=" ") 
df

> df
  a         b
1 1 colour1 O
2 2 colour2 O
3 3 colour3 O
4 4 colour4 O
5 5 soundi In
6 6 soundr In
7 7 sounde In
8 8 soundw In
```